# Ridiculous Gray borders around images

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

I've tried every suggested combination from previous questions in an effort to remove the gray border from my image buttons, as you can see from the code, when the image is clicked it opens a content pane below the button: `border:none`, `border:0px`, etc.

Nothing seems to be working. CSS can be extremely frustrating.

Below is the css and html I'm working with, stripped of the above fix attempts since they'd didn't seem to work. I'm hoping it is something as simple as me overlooking or screwing something up.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#basemapbutton {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:150px;
    width:20px;
    height:40px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

and:

```
<!--Basemap Gallery-->      
<div id="basemapbutton">
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" baseClass="tomButton" border="0" title="Switch Basemap">    
    <img src="images/imgBaseMap.png"/>     
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">   
        toggler[(dojo.style("panel","display") == "none") ? 'show':'hide']();
    </script>
    </button>   
    <div id="panel" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="#900;display: none;">
        <span id="basemapGallery"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first of all CSS could be tricky. So put img on top of everything in your css file and the img tag should not have anywhere else border information as CSS will take that info rather than `img {border : none;}`

Comment: I'm betting the border is on another element. Try adding the CSS "border:0" to each element and see which one makes the border go away.

Comment: If you aren't already, you should use a tool like Firefox + Firebug to troubleshoot CSS issues.  It will show you the CSS being applied to any object in the page and shows you what file (and line number) that the style was defined in.

Comment: it could be also a box-shadow applied

Comment: wats the final solution which worked for u?  @Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add at the top of your main CSS file this:

```
img {

border: 0px !important;
outline: 0 !important;

}
```

**!important** will override every inline style that could be added by javascript...

Comment: As far as I see, the border doesn't come from the img-tag, but is the button background, because the button has some padding.

Comment: Expanding on @WouterH comment: I added the following CSS which removed the gray border:

    .dijitButtonNode {  
        border: 0px !important; 
  z-index:100;
  padding:0px;
 }

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Craig: the css in my answer should have worked fine, can you test it for the sake of completeness? :)

Comment: @WouterH I tested it and it didn't remove the border. For whatever reason it displaced where the buttons were placed on the page???

Comment: In my case it was really the <button> that had padding and border. This style applied to button worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the button element and/or the div element around the `<img>`.

```
#basemapbutton img, button img,
#basemapbutton:active img, button:active img
#basemapbutton:focus img, button:focus img {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use content: ""; in css style.

```
#basemapbutton {
    content: "";

    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:150px;
    width:20px;
    height:40px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
#basemapbutton button {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cretae one class for the button like this `<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" baseClass="tomButton" class="remove_border" title="Switch Basemap">`

Just include this point in your css for this class `.remove_border{ border-style:none; padding:0px;}`